# Curved labels on curved arrows

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator, curved

I have straight lines in a metric CRS, connecting two points. So each line has exactly two vertices. I want to display these lines as curved arrows with curved labels above these arrows. QGIS version is 3.22.

To get the curved arrow, I am using geometry generator with a curved arrow on top of it. As expression I am using:

```
make_line(start_point($geometry), translate(centroid($geometry),length($geometry)/6,length($geometry)/6),end_point($geometry))
```

[image]

But since this curved arrow is constructed via geometry generator, the label is still displayed on top of the actual line:

[image]

**Is there a way to define a rule for the label to follow the path from the curved arrow?**

Note, that the line from geometry generator is actually not curved as shown below. So following this path would not be enough.

[image]

*I would really like to avoid creating new layers, but if there is absolutely no way to define a rule for the label to follow the arrow, I could also live with a solution that modifies the actual geometry to make smooth curves via PostGIS.*

Answer (score 6):

A quite ok solution, but not perfect:

Use this expression for the symbology via geometry generator as well as for the label via geometry generator:

```
smooth(make_line(start_point($geometry),project(centroid($geometry),length($geometry)/6,radians(line_interpolate_angle($geometry,length($geometry)/2)+90)),end_point($geometry)),10)
```

Note the `smooth()` function. Play around with the number of iterations, to find a low number looking good.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Resulting in a little offset:

[image]